# Apache/PHP segmentation fault in debug_backtrace()

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, debug-backtrace

When performing a specific action in a Drupal project, PHP crashes.
In `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I can see:

> [Wed Jul 08 09:51:13.068078 2015] [core:notice] [pid 9130] AH00051: child pid 9135 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Using `xdebug.auto_trace=On`, I've been able to determine that the crash occurs when `debug_backtrace()` is called (and not every time).

I've managed to get a core dump. Here's what I get when running `sudo gdb /usr/sbin/apache2 /tmp/coredumps/core-apache2.9135`:

> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>    #0  0x00007f12e1c7422a in zend_std_object_get_class_name () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

What can I do to further troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: I am having this exact issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @DavidCorpstein I used a workaround: I put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);` in my `settings.php` file, to disable Strict Warnings, so that `debug_backtrace()` does not get called anymore. In my case, the strict warning was caused by the Mail MIME module (Drupal 7).